# Is uniform continuity the globalization of a local property?

Tags: real-analysis

Let us work within the space of real numbers, R. Continuity of f is simply equivalent (in fact, can be defined as) to "continuous at x, for all x". Is there some property P such that uniform continuity of f is equivalent to "P at x, for all x"?

Comment: You don't talk of uniform continuity **at a point**. It is defined on a **set**.

Comment: Continuity, in one sense, can be thought of as a property of certain pairs (f, r) where f is a function on the reals and r is a real. Let us call this C(f, r). Continuity of f is equivalent to "for all r, C(f,r)". Is uniform continuity of f equivalent to "for all r, P(f, r)" for some P?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that such a property exists.

Consider the following situation:   $(I_n)_n$ a family of open intervals that cover $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ so that $f$ is uniformly continuous on every interval $I_n$. Let  $r$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $r$ is in some $I_n$. Since the function $f$ is uniformly continuous on $I_n$  we have the property $P(f,r)$. Since $r$ was arbitrary it follows that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Conclusion: whenever a function is locally uniform continuous it follows that it is also uniformly continuous. But this is a false statement: as a counterexample, take the function $f(r)= r^2$.

Hence, no such property exists. The idea is: uniform continuity is not a local property, so also not a "point property".

Comment: I now realize my question is trivial. Simply take P(f,r) to be "f is uniformly continuous". And of course, this is true for any property of functions. Your proof is not wrong, but it addresses a slightly different question. My question is only concerned with functions that are uniformly continuous functions over R, not over any smaller domain.

Comment: You can \emph{make} your question trivial in this way if you wish. The title suggests otherwise.